# git Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)

Tags: git, ssh, rsa

I have a public/private rsa key pair. I can connect to remote server with ssh, but when I do `git pull origin master` I get this error:

> Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic). fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository.
>
> Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository
>   exists.

My git client run `ubuntu 14.04` and my public private key is in the folder `$HOME\.ssh`.

I tried to do `sudo chmod -R 777 folder` but without any success.

Comment: $HOME\.ssh should be readable only by owner - in other setting you may have a problem with connections

Answer (score 3):

> sudo chmod -R 777 folder but without any success.

That would never work, as any folder with *writing* right would make ssh fail immediately.

You need to make sure that:

- you have generate the ssh key pair properly:

  ```
  ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"
  ```

(I recommend *not* setting a passphrase at first, at least for testing)

- the right associate with your ~/.ssh/id_rsa(.pub) are correct.
  At least:

  ```
  chmod 700 /home/<login>/.ssh
  chmod 600 /home/<login>/.ssh/authorized_keys
  ```
- the ssh url is correct.
  For instance, GitHub would use git@github.com:user/repo
- your ssh key is registered to your account ([Example for GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/))

Answer (score 0):

If you are using macos and have updated to the latest os Ventura, you can try adding two lines

```
HostkeyAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
PubkeyAcceptedAlgorithms +ssh-rsa
```

to the end of the file `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`, just like this
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this command to check your key
ssh -T git@github.com

Also you need to check if your remote url is added to git config correctly.

Comment: how does this check your key?