# Issue using git pull

Tags: git, ssh, gitlab, ssh-keys, ssh-keygen

I get an issue using `sudo git pull origin master`, I generated a SSH-KEY and I added them on Gitlab, but my command doesn't work...

Commands :

```
****:/var/www/****$ cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQ****4rZZwQjt0VmJdb8zGQwcNMsYAZTCssjNw1UQZqTSUZRy8uK76W9h9kXsVgggAf1EgUKaxaKFFMF50TtugkdsSIGq4/ze9vYDrEVy4rc4aOTPuBNI9X01JRbvUdRtOajmC8WEq5NdLUwXCtg/Cga2uZ ****
****:/var/www/****$ sudo git pull origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
****:/var/www/****$
```

Comment: Probably root's ssh is not configured to use your user's key in `~/.ssh`.

Comment: Ok and what am I supposed to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure and register a ssh (public and private) key in the $HOME (~) of the user which will execute `git pull origin master`

If you want to use root (which is not ideal), then the `id_rsa.pub` (and `id_rsa`) should be in `/root/.ssh` (with [the right permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626619/6309))

As [Martin Nyolt[2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1314743/martin-nyolt) adds in the comments, follow the [GitLab documentation about ssh](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html), especially the section "[Tip: Non-default OpenSSH key file names or locations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html#tip-non-default-openssh-key-file-names-or-locations)".

Comment: Alternatively, follow the [gitlab guide's](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ssh/README.html) section "Non-default OpenSSH key file names or locations", and set up root's SSH to use the other user's identity file. But definitely, using another user (maybe `www_git` in the `www` group) should be the first step.

Comment: @MartinNyolt I agree. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.