# In Docker, git-lfs giving error: credentials for https://github.... not found

Tags: git, docker, git-lfs

I am trying to pull large files into a Docker container from git using git-lfs. Unfortunately, I keep getting the error:

```
...

 ---> f07e7087dc5a
Step 13/16 : RUN git lfs pull
 ---> Running in a387e389eebd
batch response: Git credentials for https://github.XXXX.edu/XXXXX/XXXXXXXXX.git not found.
error: failed to fetch some objects from 'https://github.XXXX.edu/XXXXX/XXXXXXXXX.git/info/lfs'
The command '/bin/sh -c git lfs pull' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Any idea how to fix this and get my files pulled correctly and error-free? I am running the following in Docker to try to get git-lfs to work:

```
# Get git-lfs and pull down the large files
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-utils && apt-get install -y curl
RUN curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | bash
RUN apt-get install -y git-lfs
RUN git lfs install
RUN git lfs pull
```

I add my `.gitattributes` file and `.git` file to the Docker image as well.

**EDIT**: Can I maybe somehow use:

```
https://you:password@github.com/you/example.git
```

or

```
git config remote.origin.url https://you:password@github.com/you/example.git
```

Comment: Your edit is on the right track. You can try `RUN git remote add origin https://you:password@github.com/you/example.git` before your `pull` line. If it fails because `origin` already exists, then you should modify the `.git` file you're copying into the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> May be I can use `https://you:password@github.com/you/example.git`:

That is a bad practice, as anyone doing a `docker image history` on your built image would get those credentials back.

It is better to do a multi-stage build, as described in "[Access Private Repositories from Your Dockerfile Without Leaving Behind Your SSH Keys](https://vsupalov.com/build-docker-image-clone-private-repo-ssh-key/)".

It uses an SSH key instead of username/password because:

- you can generate and register an SSH key dedicated for your docker build.
- you can revoke that key at any time, since it is used only `for this docker build` (as opposed to a credential password you cannot easily change without impacting possibly other scripts using said password)

Your Dockerfile would look like:

```
# this is our first build stage, it will not persist in the final image
FROM ubuntu as intermediate

# install git
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y git

# add credentials on build
ARG SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
RUN mkdir /root/.ssh/
RUN echo "${SSH_PRIVATE_KEY}" > /root/.ssh/id_rsa

# make sure your domain is accepted
RUN touch /root/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts

RUN git clone git@bitbucket.org:your-user/your-repo.git

FROM ubuntu
# copy the repository form the previous image
COPY --from=intermediate /your-repo /srv/your-repo
# ... actually use the repo :)
```

---

Warning, March 2023, regarding `github.com` SSH access:

### "[GitHub has updated its RSA SSH host key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47708298/6309)"

---

Comment: So I changed a few things. Namely, `RUN ssh-keyscan github.mit.edu >> /root/.ssh/known_hosts` and then also `RUN git clone https://github.mit.edu/user/users-repo.git`. But this is a private repository and it is through the enterprise version of github, so when I run things, I get the error: `Cloning into 'users-repo'...
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.mit.edu': No such device or address`

Comment: @agaidis Yes. That is why I suggest creating an SSH key dedicated for that clone. Using an *SSH* URL: `RUN gt clone git@github.mit.edu/user/users-repo.git`

Comment: Now I get: `Cloning into 'users-repo'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'xx.x.xx.xx' to the list of known hosts.
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
Permissions 0644 for '/root/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": bad permissions
git@github.mit.edu: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

Comment: Would I want to do something like `RUN chmod 400 ~/.ssh/id_rsa` as seen in this stackoverflow post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29933918/ssh-key-permissions-0644-for-id-rsa-pub-are-too-open-on-mac

Comment: @agaidis yes indeed: the permissions need to be strict enough for SSH to work. I usually use https://stackoverflow.com/a/37626619/6309

Comment: I tried that and now I am getting: `Cloning into 'users-repo'...
Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address 'xx.x.xx.xx' to the list of known hosts.
Load key "/root/.ssh/id_rsa": invalid format
git@github.mit.edu: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.` Any thoughts??

Comment: @agaidis Yes: docker or not, you need to make sure the public key (\m/id_rsa.pub`) has been published in your private GitHub, for the user 'user' in his/her SSH keys page.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173833/discussion-between-agaidis-and-vonc).